# System monitoring tools

Tags: networking, monitoring, network-monitor, system-monitor, resource-management

I need a recommendation for system monitoring tools among these options. I'm specifically within a Devops team if that narrows the selection down.

What are your recommendations? Any pros/cons?

Solarwind vs Nagios vs Prematheos vs [any tools you might have in mind].

Comment: On what OS should it run, and what kind of features do you need? Remember we don't feature product comparisons (see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185)). Also, what is your budget? Or must the tool come for free?

Comment: That is a fair question. But I am looking for comparisons in various factors including the ones you mentioned, mostly what is concerned for a devops in a mid-size company.

Comment: As I mentioned, Tina, comparisons are off-topic here. And you still haven't mentioned the OS or the features needed – so it's much too broad, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Answer (score 1):

I'am working with rollbar.

I'm very pleased. The implementation was very simple. 
In addition, the first 5000 events are free of charge.

I use the Ruby SDK.

Her you find the features: https://rollbar.com/product/

Answer (score 1):

[Sentry](https://Sentry.io) is an event logging platform focused on capturing and aggregating exceptions. Sentry notifies you when your users experience errors in your web and mobile apps and easely you can track them. And, if you wish, it can gives you a monthly report of your scenario.

It has integración with several [platforms](https://sentry.io/platforms/) .